# whatsapp-web.js how save downloadMedia()

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, fs

**Hi, I'm new to this and I have a question that breaks my head,
I'm using whatsapp-web.js 1.12.6, but when I download a multimedia file I can't find how to save it ...
I am trying to do with fs.writefile, but it throws me an error
How to save that object as a file?**

```
const listenMessage = () => {
      client.on("message", async (inboundMsg) => {
        console.log(inboundMsg);
    
        const { from, to, body, hasMedia, mediaKey } = inboundMsg;
    
        if (hasMedia) {
          const mediafile = await inboundMsg.downloadMedia();
          console.log(
            mediafile.mimetype,
            mediafile.filename,
            mediafile.data.length
          );
            
          //How to save that object as a file? =====================================
    
          fs.writeFile('./upload/', JSON.stringify(mediafile.data), function (err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
    
          //========================================================================
    
    
          var post = {
            message: body,
            direction: "inbound",
            number: from,
            media: "mymediafile",
          };
          var query = pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO chat SET ?",
            post,
            function (error, results, fields) {
              if (error) throw error;
              console.log(from, to, body, hasMedia);
            }
          );
        } else {
          var post = {
            message: body,
            direction: "inbound",
            number: from,
          };
          var query = pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO chat SET ?",
            post,
            function (error, results, fields) {
              if (error) throw error;
              console.log(from, to, body);
            }
          );
        }
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure u have the folder './upload' created on your work directory and Try this:

```
fs.writeFile(
  "./upload/" + mediafile.filename,
  mediafile.data,
  "base64",
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same line of reasoning, but now how do I make it so that I can read these files, test this and it didn't work

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.body === 'img') {
    fs.readFile("./upload/undefined", function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(data)
      const media = new MessageMedia('image/png', data);
      client.sendMessage(message.from, media);
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In project file, create a folder that name is img.
Then if you will get files in your folder. Pdf, images, rar files can be downloaded.

- /img/phoneNumber_WhatsappNotifyName/YYYY-MM-DD/HH-II-SS_filename.filetype

```
whatsapp.on('message', async msg => {
    const time = new Date(msg.timestamp * 1000).toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').split(' ')[1].replaceAll(':', '-')
    const date = new Date(msg.timestamp * 1000).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    const person = msg['_data']['notifyName'];
    const phoneNumber = msg.from.replaceAll('@c.us', '');
    if (msg.hasMedia) {
        const media = await msg.downloadMedia();
        const folder = process.cwd() + '/img/' + phoneNumber + '_' + person + '/' + date + '/';
        const filename = folder + time + '_' + msg.id.id + '.' + media.mimetype.split('/')[1];
        fs.mkdirSync(folder, { recursive: true });
        fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(media.data, 'base64').toString('binary'), 'binary');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code looks great. But there are cases like audio "opus" that the extension needs to be adjusted. Example: mimetype: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus', there is the ; with more information that affects the file extension... A working code could be media.mimetype.split("/")[1].split(";", 2)[0]; It wouldn't be ideal, but functional. The "mime-types" or "mime-db" npm packages may work in some cases as well.